# Can Java Axis Client ignore the newly added WSDL fields?

Tags: java, axis

I have a webservice in Java and client both using Axis. I changed my Service (WSDL) and added a new field in the response message. Do we need to recompile the client? Or the existing client can work with the new service interface without recompiling it? It appears the client is throwing a SAXException on seeing the new field in the response message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to recompile the client.

When parsing the XML, the SAX will look for the corresponding field to store the value and will not find it, then it will throw the Exception. The XML may be versatile and easy to modify, but the classes that it is translated into are not.

Comment: Is there anything in the spec which states that the client should file if there is an extra element in the Response message compared to the WSDL contract?

Comment: Is there anyway to ignore those fields